# ¿Cuál es la abreviatura correcta para "doña"?

Tags: ortografía, abreviaturas

Aquí va otra de mis preguntas de carretera. Junto a El Puerto de Santa María (Cádiz, España) hay una pequeña pedanía que se llama [Poblado de Doña Blanca](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poblado_de_Do%C3%B1a_Blanca), un pueblo de colonización que empieza a gestarse en 1955 para, sobre todo, dar cabida a las personas perjudicadas por la expropiación de terrenos para la construcción de la base de Rota.

El caso es que para llegar allí me he fijado en que las señales abrevian el nombre del pueblo, y de diferentes formas. Véanse estos dos ejemplos:

[image: Poblado Dª Blanca]

[image: Poblado Dña. Blanca]

Vemos que tenemos dos opciones para abreviar "doña":

- Dª
- Dña.

¿Cuál de las dos opciones es la correcta (o la más aconsejada)? ¿Lo son las dos? ¿No lo es ninguna? A mí al menos la segunda me chirría un poco porque creo recordar que la RAE desaconseja las abreviaturas si tan solo se va a omitir una letra, pero no estoy seguro de si eso se refiere solamente a la última letra de la palabra (como habría ocurrido con "doñ.") o a cualquiera de las intermedias.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Según la RAE, ambas son válidas:

http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/abreviaturas

> *D.ª*: doña (también *Dña.*; cf. *D.*)